# Symfony dynamic fixtures foreign key

Tags: php, symfony1

It's possible to embed php code in symfony's yml fixture file. My table entry needs a foreign key id. Is it possible through the embedded php to get the last inserted id of the referenced table or any other way which doesn't involve setting the foreign ids manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use ids in your fixture. Do not use foreign_key columns. Use relations instead, like this:

```
ACLass:
  a_instance:
    title: 'pwet'

BClass:
  b_instance:
    name: My b object
    AObject: a_instance
```